# How can I add arrows to the side of my tikzpicture with horizontally stacked bar?

Tags: pgfplots, labels

The drawn out image is what I want. I already have the horizontal bars, I just need the y-axis labels. Also, how can I add percentages to the x-axis values and to the values inside the bars? This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,6); %create a bounding box to reserve space
        %\begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{.79}}
        \begin{axis}[
        name=MyAxis,
        xbar stacked,
        width=10cm, height=10.0cm, 
        bar width=8pt,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={
            font=\scriptsize,
        },
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        %enlargelimits=0.15,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        %enlargelimits=0.07,
        legend style={at={(0.5,1)}, anchor=south, legend columns=-1, draw=none},
        tick label style={font=\small}, 
        %tickwidth = 0pt, 
        ylabel={Label 1},
        symbolic y coords={P11, P12, P61, P62, P81, P82},
        ytick=data,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (50,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (50,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (25,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (25,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot[color=violet, fill=violet!50] coordinates {(4,P11) (8,P12) (1,P61) (2,P62) (5,P81) (19,P82)};
        \legend{\strut A, \strut D, \strut L, \strut P, \strut T}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: "I  already have …" Yes, do show us what you've already got. People are happy to help, but generally more inclined to when you have made a noticeable effort yourself. Make sure to post a full (i.e., compilable) example.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far, as this will help others help you. There are several ways to draw the above and it will be probably most helpful for you if you receive an answer that is based to the code you started with.

Comment: You could put `\draw[<->] (yticklabel cs:0) -- (yticklabel cs:0.5) node[midway, left] {Label 1};`, but for this to show, you'd need to add the option `clip=false` to the `axis` environment. This, in turn, would show the full bars to the right that are currently clipped away.

Comment: You could also place coordinates inside the `axis` environment, such as `\coordinate (A) at (yticklabel cs:0); \coordinate (B) at (yticklabel cs:0.5);` and then, outside the `axis` environment, put `\draw[<->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] (A) -- (B) node[midway, left] {Label 1};`, which would also work without `clip=false` being set.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the major part of the bars in the diagram is clipped away due to your settings, but I take it that this is intended. In general, you could make use of `yticklabel cs` to draw something next to the *y* tick labels, for example using `\draw[<->] (yticklabel cs:0) -- (yticklabel cs:0.5) node[midway, left] {Label 1};`. However, since you seemingly need to clip the plot, you cannot do this directly inside the `axis` environment as it would be clipped away along with the plot. A workaround would be to place `\coordinate`s inside the `axis` environment and use these to draw the things at the labels outside of the environment.

So, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        name=MyAxis,
        xbar stacked,
        width=10cm, height=10cm, 
        bar width=8pt,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={
            font=\scriptsize,
        },
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        %enlargelimits=0.15,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        %enlargelimits=0.07,
        legend style={at={(0.5,1)}, anchor=south, legend columns=-1, draw=none},
        tick label style={font=\small}, 
        %tickwidth = 0pt, 
        %ylabel={},
        symbolic y coords={P11, P12, P61, P62, P81, P82},
        ytick=data,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (50,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (50,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (25,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot coordinates {(70,P11) (25,P12) (74,P61) (65,P62) (55,P81) (43,P82)};
        \addplot[color=violet, fill=violet!50] coordinates {(4,P11) (8,P12) (1,P61) (2,P62) (5,P81) (19,P82)};
        \legend{\strut A, \strut D, \strut L, \strut P, \strut T}

        \coordinate (A) at (yticklabel cs:0);
        \coordinate (B) at (yticklabel cs:0.5);
        \coordinate (C) at (yticklabel cs:1);
    \end{axis}
    \draw[<->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] (A) -- (B) node[midway, left] {Label 1}; 
    \draw[<->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] (B) -- (C) node[midway, left] {Label 2}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]